# os.path.exists returns wrong result

Tags: python, windows

I'm using an already existed path in my program but the `os.path.exists()` method returns `False`. The script bellow shows the behavior:

```
import os

permission_path = 'Security\Permission'
android_permission_path = permission_path + '\android'

os.path.exists(permission_path) #returns True as expected
os.path.exists(android_permission_path) # returns False unexpectedly!
```

I'm sure that the path `Security\Permission\android` is already exist. Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

I'm on `windows` running `Python 2.7.13`.

Comment: I see *android* and *Android* , I'm not a windows user don't know how case sens. is handled

Comment: @hootnot it's _android_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join paths in a portable way:

```
permission_path = os.path.join('Security', 'Permission')
android_permission_path = os.path.join(permission_path, 'android')

os.path.exists(permission_path) 
os.path.exists(android_permission_path)
```

Other problem that you may have is lack of access rights to 'Security/Permission/android' directory.

Comment: The problem is `'\a'` is ASCII BEL (0x07). Using `os.path.join` avoids this problem.